# Custom loss function in Keras based on the input data

Tags: keras

I am trying to create the custom loss function using Keras. I want to compute the loss function based on the input and predicted the output of the neural network.

I tried using the customloss function in Keras. I think y_true is the output that we give for training and y_pred is the predicted output of the neural network. The below loss function is same as "mean_squared_error" loss in Keras.

```
def customloss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

I would like to use the input to the neural network also to compute the custom loss function in addition to mean_squared_error loss. Is there a way to send an input to the neural network as an argument to the customloss function.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66966915/10375049

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I have come across 2 solutions to the question you asked.

1. You can pass your input (scalar only) as an argument to the custom loss wrapper function.

```
    def custom_loss(i):

        def loss(y_true, y_pred):
            return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1) + something with i...
        return loss

    def baseline_model():
        # create model
        i = Input(shape=(5,))
        x = Dense(5, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='linear')(i)
        o = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='linear')(x)
        model = Model(i, o)
        model.compile(loss=custom_loss(i), optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0005))
        return model
```

This solution is also mentioned in [the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46464549/keras-custom-loss-function-accessing-current-input-pattern)

2. You can pad your label with extra data columns from input and write a custom loss. This is helpful if you just want one/few feature column(s) from your input.

```
    def custom_loss(data, y_pred):

        y_true = data[:, 0]
        i = data[:, 1]
        return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1) + something with i...


    def baseline_model():
        # create model
        i = Input(shape=(5,))
        x = Dense(5, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='linear')(i)
        o = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='linear')(x)
        model = Model(i, o)
        model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0005))
        return model


    model.fit(X, np.append(Y_true, X[:, 0], axis =1), batch_size = batch_size, epochs=90, shuffle=True, verbose=1)
```

This solution can be found also here in this [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/8gziht/p_keras_accessing_feature_indices_from_custom/).

I have only used the 2nd method when I had to use input feature columns in the loss. The first method can be only used with scalar arguments as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I'm very late to the party, but your second solution is just genius! Very very practical, awesome.

Comment: Doing so I am getting: `tensorflow.python.eager.core._SymbolicException: Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors, but found [<tf.Tensor 'mel_specs:0' shape=(None, None, 512) dtype=float32>]`. Not that I am passing a `tf.data.Dataset` to the `fit()` function. Any idea what the problem is here?

Comment: I am having trouble using the first method. I get this error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'input_tensor' referenced before assignment`

Comment: In the 2nd method, 2 columns are passed as y for model.fit(x, y). If we make predictions using the trained model, what column does it predict? @Anakin

Comment: I've just implemented your 2nd solution and it works like a charm ! I concur with Jean-Pierre - 'just genius'. Thx

Comment: @Anakin The 1st method does **not** work with tensor input, like, for example, input layer of the model.

Comment: When I use the 2nd method, I get "No gradients provided for any variable" even after ensuring the loss function is entirely differentiable.

Answer (score 5):

You could wrap your custom loss with another function that takes the input tensor as an argument:

```
def customloss(x):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        # Use x here as you wish
        err = K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
        return err

    return loss
```

And then compile your model as follows:

```
model.compile('sgd', customloss(x))
```

where `x` is your input tensor.

**NOTE**: Not tested.

Comment: What is y_true and y_pred? Is it the tensor or just the scalar for one input? I want to send an input x corresponding to y_true. Is the loss calculated individually for each element of ytrain tensor (output of the Keras model) or for the whole tensor? Thank you.

Comment: `y_true` is the label's tensor, while `y_pred` is the network prediction's tensor. As for the other question, I don't understand what is being asked.

Comment: y_pred will be for certain input to the model. I would like to access that input tensor. Is there any way to send an input tensor to the customloss function? thank you.

Comment: You can pass the input tensor via the argument `x` of `customloss`