# Custom loss function error in Tensorflow when passing model inputs as an argument (with y_true and y_pred)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

Using Tensorflow 2.10, I am trying to implement a custom loss function that takes the model inputs as well as y_true and y_pred arguments.

```
inputs  = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=X.shape[-1:], batch_size=16)
dense1  = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(inputs)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense1)
model   = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

def custom_loss(i):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        mask = tf.equal(y_true, tf.cast(tf.round(y_pred), 'float32'))
        selec = tf.where(mask, 1., 0.)
        x1 = (1 - tf.reduce_mean(selec))
        mask = tf.reshape(selec, (-1,))
        m = tf.boolean_mask(i, mask)
        x2 = tf.reduce_mean(m[:, -1])
        return x1 * x2
    return loss

model.compile(loss=custom_loss(inputs),
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy',
                       tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision')])

h = model.fit(X_train,
              y_train,
              validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
              epochs=5,
              batch_size=16,
              verbose=2)
```

When trying to fit the model I got the following error:

```
TypeError: You are passing KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='Placeholder:0', description="created by layer 'tf.cast_17'"), an intermediate Keras symbolic input/output, to a TF API that does not allow registering custom dispatchers, such as `tf.cond`, `tf.function`, gradient tapes, or `tf.map_fn`. Keras Functional model construction only supports TF API calls that *do* support dispatching, such as `tf.math.add` or `tf.reshape`. Other APIs cannot be called directly on symbolic Kerasinputs/outputs. You can work around this limitation by putting the operation in a custom Keras layer `call` and calling that layer on this symbolic input/output.
```

Similar posts proposed to disable eager execution:

```
from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import disable_eager_execution
disable_eager_execution()
```

But this leads to another error in the loss function:

```
ValueError: Variable <tf.Variable 'dense_14/kernel:0' shape=(13, 8) dtype=float32> has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

Comment: Have you tried model.add_loss? Maybe this will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68754599/tensorflow-use-input-in-loss-function

Comment: Thanks. I tried this solution but got another error:
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable [all of my layers]

Comment: You are using functions that are not differentiable, like boolean_mask and equals.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I did some test out of curiosity; it seems that `boolean_mask` and `equal` allow the flow of gradient for the selected elements while the unselected elements are assigned the gradient of zero. Can you please double check and let me know? Please let me know if more information is needed. Thanks.

Comment: The gradient of equals is not mathematically defined, so no, what you said makes no sense. You cannot use equals in a loss function.

Comment: cast and round also have no defined gradients.